# PHP Accessing parent class variable through extended class after overriding in child class

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, overriding

How can we access the original parent class variable through child class, if child class overrides it after extending.

```
class SimpleClass{
    public $var = 'This is Parent';

    public function getVar(){
        return $this->var;
    }
}

class ExtendClass extends SimpleClass{
    public $var = 'This is Child';

    public function getParent(){
        return parent::getVar();
    }
}

$obj = new ExtendClass();

echo $obj->getParent(); // Prints 'This is Child'
```

I'm sure it has something to do something with $this pseudo-variable, because i'm constructing ExtendClass, in that context $this only have access to the overridden $var variable.

So i tried to statically access the variable through class methods.

```
class SimpleClass{
    public static $var = 'This is Parent';

    public function getVar(){
       return self::$var;
    }
}

class ExtendClass extends SimpleClass{
    public static $var = 'This is Child';

    public function getParentVar(){
        return parent::getVar();
    }

    public function getChildVar(){
        return self::$var;
    }
}

$obj = new ExtendClass();

echo $obj->getParentVar();// Prints 'This is Parent'

echo $obj->getChildVar();// Print 'This is Child'
```

It worked, but how can we non-statically access the parent class variable through getVar() method of Parent class.

Comment: I don't understand why you need same variable name on both class. Simple keep one.If you need two variable use two variable name.

Comment: Is it the default value you want to access? It doesn't make sense otherwise, I suppose, because in object context there wouldn't really be a parent different from the child instance.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the child class explicitly backups the original value before editing it, you can't access the *parent's value* of a class member since there isn't a *parent's value*. Both child and parent class' code share the **same** variable.

Comment: You could retrieve its default value with `ReflectionClass` but thats another can of worms entirely.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Hmmm, I didn't read the question carefully enough. In this case - an explicit default value declared in the class head - reflection is the answer. Why not preparing an example?...

Comment: I'm getting clarification from the OP and will post an answer if this is indeed the need.